# Buildroot use classic GNU package instead of BusyBox one

Tags: mount, embedded, busybox, buildroot

I'm wondering how to use the "classic" GNU tools instead of BusyBox ones for a specific command.

The command I want to act like on a classic Linux is mount, but I think it's the same for every command stripped in BusyBox binary.

My problem is that I'm deploying a project calling `mount -c ...` and `-c` option is not recognized by Busybox and I don't want to modify project's sources.

I have seen that I could disable the integration of mount in busybox by running `make busybox-menuconfig` however I can't find `mount` inside buildroot menuconfig. 
I didn't find any information about using "classic" GNU tools from buildroot neither.

Does anybody know how to use "clasic" `mount` command and keeping busybox for others ?

Answer (score 0):

Does busybox also remap file paths?  In other words, do:

```
# mount -c blah /dev/blah
```

work the same as:

```
# /bin/mount -c blah /dev/blah
```

Always use absolute paths to all applications when writing a script that will run as root.

Comment: Though your answer may solve OP's problem, it doesn't answer the question at all. I think OP wanted the GNU mount instead of BusyBox mount in Buildroot options.